# referencing a range of papers

Tags: bibliographies

In fact, I have checked a previous post about citing range of papers (using numerc keys). The problem is that I am having an error saying option clash for package natbib when I want to follow the examples. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}


\title{Sample article to present \texttt{elsarticle} class\tnoteref{label0}}
 \tnotetext[label0]{This is only an example}

\section{Introduction}
BLA BLA BLA \cite{ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4}


\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\bibliography{sample}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It is missing one brace in `\cite{}`, or better, there is an extra one opening.

Comment: Yes this because I type it too fast but the problem is stillt here I am using TeXniCenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, we find in `.log`

> ```
> The package natbib has already been loaded with options:
>   [numbers]
> There has now been an attempt to load it with options
>   [numbers,sort&compress]
> Adding the global options:
>   numbers,numbers,sort&compress
> to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
> ```

So, the first try to fix is:

1. delete `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`
2. pass the options to the class instead

   ```
   \documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p,numbers,sort,compress]{elsarticle}
   ```

Comment: It's okay everything works fine now thank you very much